# Flutter Bluetooth Null Check Exception although null was checked

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, nullpointerexception

Here is the `main()` function. Here is the initializisation of the "flutter_isolate" library

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

...
```

```
class BTConnection {
  BluetoothConnection? c;
  Future<void> connect(address) async {
    print('Connecting to the device ...');

    BluetoothConnection connection =
        await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
    c = connection;
    print('Connected to the device');
    FlutterIsolate.spawn(listenToData, connection);
  }

  Future<void> disconnect() async {
    if (c != null) {
      await c?.finish();
      print("disconnected from device");
    } else {
      print("There is no bluetooth connection to disconnect");
    }
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  Future<void> listenToData(connection) async {
    print("listening ...");
    await connection.input?.listen((Uint8List data) {
      print('Data incoming: ${ascii.decode(data)}');
      connection.output.add(data); // Sending data
    }).onDone(() {
      print('Disconnected by remote request');
    });
  }
}
```

Whenever I run the code and enter the correct MAC address in the text field, the function `connect()` is called and after a few seconds the message "Connected to the device" is printed. The following error message is then output:

```
E/flutter (26066): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (26066): #0      FlutterIsolate.spawn
flutter_isolate.dart:28
E/flutter (26066): #1      BTConnection.connect
main.dart:110
E/flutter (26066): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26066): #2      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>
main.dart:70
E/flutter (26066): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26066):
```

Comment: What is line 28 of `flutter_isolate.dart`?

Comment: I am using the library flutter_isolate from pub.dev

Comment: Looking at the source code to `flutter_isolate`, the failed null-check is from `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(entryPoint)!`.  It has nothing to do with your `connection` check.  Always inspect the code that directly caused the exception.  I'm not familiar with this package and don't know if you're missing some initialization step, but maybe that provides you with some insight.

Comment: I've now written my program to work without the library. Now the error doesn't occur anymore, but it exists when I use the library